# Nested change event still happens when disabled

Tags: javascript, events

I want the `categorycb_change` function NOT to be executed when `permissioncb_change` is in progress, but it does not work.

In the code below I set `fireCategoryEvents` to `false` when `permissioncb_change` is executing, however for some reason this does not prevent `category_cb` from executing. When I debug I can see that `permissioncb_change` is done first and only when it is done executing `categorycb_change` is fired.

(Important note: `categorycb_change` is triggered within `updateGroupCheckboxes` within the `permissioncb_change` function.)

I also tried this with unbinding and rebinding, but the same problem.

What am I doing wrong and or how can I fix this?

`.permissioncheckbox` and `.rolecategory` are both html input checkbox elements.
the code behind `updateGroupCheckboxes` is quite complicated. so I don't think it is useful to show here. (it changes the checkedstate of multiple `.rolecategory` checkboxes so it triggers the `categorycb_change` events)

```
var fireCategoryEvents = true;

$(function () {
    $('.permissioncheckbox').change(permissioncb_change, 0);
    $('.rolecategory').change(categorycb_change);
});

function permissioncb_change() {
    fireCategoryEvents = false;
    $(this).attr('data-changed', true);
    if (firePermissionEvents) {
        updateGroupCheckboxes(this);
    }
    fireCategoryEvents = true;
}

function categorycb_change() {
    if (fireCategoryEvents) {
        alert('cat changed');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, show your HTML. Also, `updateGroupCheckboxes` code can be useful...

Comment: Olegas, The code is too large to post here, but I updated the question with some extra information.

Comment: Maybe there are some async operations there (in the `updateGroupCheckboxes`)? Some AJAX calls?

Comment: There are no AJAX or async calls in the updateGroupCheckboxes, only jQuery DOM manipulations.

Comment: Please please please change the name of variables `fireCategoryEvents` and `firePermissionEvents`. They look like functions and any developer (such as yourself later on) will probably assume they are.

Comment: Jared, I updated the question with the solution. I don't need those variables anymore. But you are correct, the naming was confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
function permissioncb_change() {
    $(this).attr('data-changed', true);
    if (arguments[0].originalEvent.srcElement.className != 'rolecategory') {
        updateGroupCheckboxes(this);
        alert('per changed');
    }
}

function categorycb_change() {
    if (arguments[0].originalEvent.srcElement.className != 'permissioncheckbox') {
        alert('cat changed');
    }
}
```

This way I check what the origin of the event was before deciding to run the code.